# Find serial port where my device is connected

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I'm starting to work with a pinpad.
I need that my program find the port where the pinpad is connected without user interaction.

I tried with:

```
Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\cimv2","SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort")

        For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
          MsgBox(queryObj("Name"))
        Next
```

but this only give me "COM1" and "COM2" as an answer (My device is connected to COM4)

and with

```
Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\cimv2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0")

        For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
            MsgBox(queryObj("Name"))
        Next
```

With this one I can see my device friendly name but I don´t know how to get the port (I receive the names like 'HP printer')

Any idea of how can I get the port that I need?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the make and model of the pin pad hardware you have connected to your serial port?

Comment: Ingenico iPP320.
The 'Friendly name' that I get with the second method is 'Ingenico control device'

Comment: Is COM4 some kind of USB-to-serial converter or a add-in Serial Port card?

Comment: I'm connecting my pinpad to a normal USB port. I 'know' that is the COM4 cause I'm reading all the ports with My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments it sounds like your device is a USB device that has a driver that causes it to appear to be (emulates) a serial port attached device. In that case I would use:

My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames

to enumerate and loop over all serial ports. Then, one at a time try to open each one and send a command to the device that you know it responds to. Most devices have some kind of heartbeat or keep alive message that they will respond to. Whichever port you get a response on is the port you need to use.

Comment: I try that solution but the thing is that there is going to be a lot of pinpads in several places and I don't know if there is going to be an issue when the machine have, for example, 10 different devices connected at the same time.

Comment: One machine will have more than one pinpad connected to it? If so, is there some kind of device identifier that you can query for over the serial interface?

Comment: There is not going to be more than one pinpad at the same time so I use your solution and it worked. Thanks!

I was afraid to create something like an eternal loop or something weird by sending a message port by port but it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I want to point 2 matters:

1: here is a solution i used for this problem (efficiancy corrections will be appreciated)
I used this soution i used to figure out on which port vx805 verifone pin pad was connected (has a unique device id):

```
Friend Class pinPadComLocater

Private Shared com As String
Private Const PNPDeviceID = "VID_11CA&PID_0220"
Private Const scope = "root\cimv2"
Public ReadOnly pinPadCom As String = Nothing


Sub New()
    If isVX805PinPadConnected() Then
        pinPadCom = com
        Output.mainLog(Output.pinpadLocationMsg + com)
    Else
        Output.mainLog(Output.pinpadNotFoundMsg)
    End If

End Sub

Private Shared Function queryCom(port As String) As Boolean
    Dim query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ClassGuid=""{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"" AND DeviceID LIKE  ""%" + PNPDeviceID + "%"" AND Caption LIKE ""%" + port + "%"""
    Dim resp = New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query).Get
    If resp.Count = 1 Then Return True  
    For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In resp
        For Each prop In queryObj.Properties 'print all data for development purposes
            Try
                Console.writeline(prop.Name + " : " + queryObj(prop.Name).ToString)
                catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Next
    Next
    Return False
End Function
Private Shared Function isVX805PinPadConnected() As Boolean
    For Each port In My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames
        Try
            If queryCom(port) Then
                com = port
                Return True
            End If
        Catch err As ManagementException
            Throw New ConstraintException("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " & err.Message)
        End Try
    Next
    Throw New ConstraintException("Pin Pad Com Port could not be located")
    Return False
End Function
```

End Class

2: would love more clarifiaction on that:

> Then, one at a time try to open each one and send a command to the device that you know it responds to. Most devices have some kind of heartbeat or keep alive message that they will respond to

I would love to see a code example of how you send such a heartbeat check to a pinpad